# What's the relationship between flink parallelism and kafka partition in producing data?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a stream job about sinking data into a Kafka topic and another stream job consuming the data in kafka topic. The configuration of the partition number of my Kafka cluster is `3`.

When I set the parallelism of the job to `4`, only 3 of the slots are busy producing data and only 3 of the consumer subtask got data.

Considering the limitation of the number of task slots, I want to change the parallelism into `1`. However, when I set the parallelism of the job to `1`, only `1 consumer task slot` got data.

In my opinion, even if I set the parallelism into 1, I'm still sinking data into 3 partitions, and can have 3 consumer subtask consuming data.

Why does only one consumer subtask working here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flink decouples storage partitioning from compute partitioning.

Each Kafka partition can be consumed by only one `KafkaSource` subtask, but a `KafkaSource` can consume from one or more partitions. Given a topic with 3 partitions, at most 3 KafkaSources can be assigned work.

With the parallelism set to one, only one slot will be used, and that slot can only have one KafkaSources (and one KafkaSink). But that one consumer can handle all 3 partitions. If the parallelism is set to 3, then 3 consumers can be busy, each handling one partition, in its own slot. With the parallelism set to 4, one slot will have an idle Kafka consumer.

In the sinks, by default each instance of the `KafkaSink` will write to each partition in round-robin fashion. You can supply a custom `FlinkKafkaPartitioner` if you wish to control to which partition each record is written, or you can use a `KafkaSerializationSchema` and specify the partition for each `ProducerRecord`.

Comment: I'm still confused on the FlinkKafkaProducer, does each one FlinkKafkaProducer just send data into one partition?

Comment: I've expanded my answer.